# use random forest to classifier review, but hat key error?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nltk, random-forest

I have follow code in python:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
forest = forest.fit( train_data_features, train["sentiment"] )
```

but have key error for "sentiment", I don't know why,

`train = pd.read_csv("labeledTrainData.tsv", header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3)`

```
-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site--packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1780, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1787, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1068, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2849, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1402, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3807)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3687)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12310)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12261)
KeyError: 'sentiment'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing the Kaggle competition? https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/data

Are you sure you have downloaded and decompressed the file ok? The first part of the file reads:

```
id      sentiment       review
"5814_8"        1       "With all this stuff go
```

This works for me:

```
>>> train = pd.read_csv("labeledTrainData.tsv", delimiter="\t")
>>> train.columns
Index([u'id', u'sentiment', u'review'], dtype='object')
>>> train.head(3)
       id  sentiment                                             review
0  5814_8          1  With all this stuff going down at the moment w...
1  2381_9          1  \The Classic War of the Worlds\" by Timothy Hi...
2  7759_3          0  The film starts with a manager (Nicholas Bell)...
```

You should check the columns are setup correctly in the `train` variable. You should have a `sentiment` column. That column seems to be missing in your dataframe.

Comment: yes, have you finished the competition? i used the original code read and clean the review well, i think it is better to try again. thanks a lot.

Comment: when use these code, how can we fill the (_file_)                                             if __name__ == '__main__':
    train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'labeledTrainData.tsv'), header=0, \
                    delimiter="\t", quoting=3)
    test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'testData.tsv'), header=0, delimiter="\t", \
                   quoting=3 )

Comment: I am not participating in the competition. Your code is poorly formatted so it is hard for me to read. The first argument to read_csv is the filename with full path. If you just clone github https://github.com/wendykan/DeepLearningMovies then the data needs to be in a subdirectory called "data".

Comment: thanks for your help, it is very helpful. I write the code step by step in the terminal by python in mac os system, it runs gut, and i got the Bag_of_word model.csv, and do you know how could i output the code totally as a .py file locally? when i later use it again to train another data, i don't have to write it again.  is it possible??

Comment: I recommend taking a look at IPython Notebook